# Shift + Mouse Scroll Wheel not working on a Mac

Tags: macos, browser, mouse

Our web app allows for the canvas to be scrolled horizontally using `Shift + the mouse wheel`.

This works for me on Windows but not on Mac (Chrome/Firefox/Safari) &  (normal mode/private & incognito mode); instead, `Shift + Scroll Wheel` scrolls vertically.

`Shift + Scroll Wheel` does scroll horizontally in Finder.

I am using a standard Lenovo scroll wheel mouse.

On the Mac, in a [JS test](https://jsfiddle.net/o58wxfms/1/), the browser console displays `Shift not pressed!` events but not `Shift pressed!` events.

On the Mac, a [2nd JS test](https://jsfiddle.net/jncf91we/1/), the browser console displays both `Shift pressed!` and `Shift not pressed!` events. The only difference in this 2nd test is the `div` contains scrollbars.

Why is my Mac not registering `Shift + Mouse Wheel` events in web browsers?